# How to programatically create transparent NSImage?

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage

Very simple: How to programatically create transparent `NSImage`? Unless it is not so simple... Previous OSX versions gave `NSImage` transparent background by default when calling

```
let image = NSImage(size: size)
```

but now it has black background. How do I create a transparent one? I want to `lockFocus()` on atransparent image of given size it and and draw.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi This is OSX question, not iOS! `UIIMage != NSImage` all libraries are different.

Comment: Do you mean to say `previous osx versions gave`? you mentioned iOS there. iOS has no NSImage.

Comment: I asked about your question. Before `let image = ` line

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi @Adev Sorry that is a typo. Should have been `Previous OSX version`, not `previous iOS version`

Comment: Typo is now fixed

Comment: You cannot create an invisible, transparent NSImage object under macOS 10.12 as the operating system places the diagonal semi-translucent symbol on it.

Answer (score 1):

A few major Mac OS versions ago the lock/unlock focus methods, while not deprecated, have been deemphasized in favor of `NSImage(size:flipped:drawingHandler:)` for deferred drawing. I have personally encountered problems with unexpectedly-rasterized text and certain alpha channel problems when composing multiple images together into one using lock/unlock in apps linked against later macOS SDKs.

My first suggestion would be to use that method and see if that resolves the issue. Your drawing handler can simply contain `return true`.

Comment: Was your issue where you were doing different types of compositing on one image...I'm having the strangest outputs.

Comment: @Chris Not sure if compositing had anything specifically to do with it, but as I said, the biggest problem was that text was always rasterized. It's been awhile so I can't remember exactly the problem with alpha but I believe it was probably text background issues.